# Display Blogtitle in HTML-Textfield

Tags: html, wordpress

On my wordpress site on the sidebar I have a text widget. I want do display the blogname (blogtitle) there. I want an HTML code, that crab and show the blogtitle by itself. I tried with this code but nothing happened:

```
<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
```

I searched on Google but didn't find anything useful.
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

When given the 'name' as parameter Wordpress looks for “Site Title” set in Settings > General. Check if this is set.

Comment: Yes. That was the first step i did